# Excel auto-generating SQL based on columns

Tags: sql, excel-2016

I know this probably isn't the best practice but my company users sometimes send me spreadsheets with values to produce manual SQL. I am so sick of writing it out. I am making a spreadsheet that they fill out which has the table name, the columns, and the values. It's almost always inserts. If you look below you'll see my column for the insert SQL which basically just goes across the line and selects the column names and then the values.

However, sometimes the number of columns can vary. So it may not go to P7, it may go to just O7 or out to Z7.

Is there a way to grab all the columns that are populated in some sort of function?

```
= "INSERT INTO "&B1&"("&A7&","&B7&","&C7&","&D7&","&E7&","&F7&","&G7&","&H7&","&I7&","&J7&","&K7&","&L7&","&M7&","&N7&","&O7&","&P7&") SELECT "&A8&","&B8&","&C8&","&D8&","&E8&","&F8&","&G8&","&H8&","&I8&","&J8&","&K8&","&L8&","&M8&","&N8&","&O8&","&P8&" "
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you give them a standard spreadsheet, they fill in whatever columns they want only, you convert that to a .csv and import into SQL

Comment: I suggested that but because there are about 100-150 columns total in the table they don't want to search around a spreadsheet for the columns they want to put info in. They just want to put down what columns they are going to use. They don't really like change much..

Answer (score 0):

I have something quite similar, for other purposes, but with a lot more complexity. This is how my code looks like, maybe you can take some ideas to your document. If you need any aditional information, please let me know.

```
Dim CounterA As Integer
For CounterA = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Dim CounterB As Integer
    CounterB = 0
    Dim CounterC As Integer
    CounterC = 0
    Dim break As Boolean
    break = False
    Dim break1 As Boolean
    break1 = False

    'Loop all column names
    Dim allColumns As String
    allColumns = ""
    CounterB = 0
    Do
        CounterB = CounterB + 1
        ColumnName = Sheets.Item(CounterA).range(Utils.Col_Letter(CounterB) & 1).Value

        If ColumnName = "" Then
            break = True
        Else
            If allColumns = "" Then
                allColumns = ColumnName
            Else
                allColumns = allColumns & ", " & ColumnName
            End If
        End If
    Loop While Not break
    CounterB = 1
    break = False

    'Loop all details
    Do
        CounterB = CounterB + 1

        Dim firstValue As String
        firstValue = Sheets.Item(CounterA).range("A" & CounterB).Value
        If firstValue = "" Then
            break1 = True
        Else
            'Loop all columns of a detail
            Dim allDetailValues As String
            allDetailValues = ""
            CounterC = 0
            break = False
            Do
                CounterC = CounterC + 1
                ColumnValue = Sheets.Item(CounterA).range(Utils.Col_Letter(CounterC) & CounterB).Text
                ColumnName = Sheets.Item(CounterA).range(Utils.Col_Letter(CounterC) & 1).Value

                ColumnValue = RTrim(ColumnValue)
                ColumnValue = Replace(ColumnValue, "'", "''")

                If ColumnName = "" Then
                    break = True
                Else
                    If allDetailValues = "" Then
                        allDetailValues = "'" + ColumnValue + "'"
                    Else
                        If ColumnValue <> "null" Then ColumnValue = "'" & ColumnValue & "'"
                        allDetailValues = allDetailValues & ", " & ColumnValue
                    End If
                End If
            Loop While Not break

            Dim insertValid As Boolean
            insertValid = InsertRecord(CS, libb_dest, Sheets.Item(CounterA).Name, allColumns, allDetailValues)
            If Not insertValid Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Loop While Not break1
Next
```

ps, you might also need this

```
Public Function Col_Letter(ByVal lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```